# How to disable all hover effects in mobile browser?

Tags: html, mobile, cross-browser

I'm working on HTML mobile app, and now I have one bug.
When I tap to link (jquery mobile 'tap' or just 'click') - I see a color trace after page has changed.
Is it any way to fix it?
I almost did it on `iOS` with  `-webkit-tap-highlight-color: #ffffff;`
but it still make my buttons bigger (I use buttons like a link, with `$().click(function(){})`
In Android's browsers it looks very-very bad.
CSS `button:hover{/*the same styles as a button{} */}` - does not work also.

Thank you.

UPD
This orange background on a screenshot that I want to disable.
[image: screen]

Comment: `button:hover{}` won't change anything (no declerations inside). You have to set the default values of it there.

Comment: Yes, it's not empty, it has the same styles as a button{} I provided more details about it.

Comment: did you set `outline:none;` ? Also try `:focus` or `:active` instead of `:hover`

Comment: Just tried it. No, no result .

Answer (score 2):

The right way is:

```
*{
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) !important; 
    -webkit-focus-ring-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) !important; 
    outline: none !important;
}
```